# The present perfect with "once": "I'll do it once I have (had) a chance"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I have read some sentences including ''once'' , ''will'' and ''perfect tense''

> 1. I will comment on this once I **have had** a chance to print it out on Monday
> 2. I will comment further on this once I **have had** a chance to fully digest it myself
> 3. The date of commencement will be confirmed once people **have indicated** an interest in taking part

As you see, first part of the sentence includes ''will'' ( future tense), second part is present perfect tense.
Is the second part of the sentence not supposed to be present tense?

> 1. I will comment on this once I **have** a chance to print it out on Monday
> 2. I will comment further on this once I **have** a chance to fully digest it myself
> 3. The date of commencement will be confirmed once people **indicate** an interest in taking part

why perfect tense?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace "once" with "after".

"I will comment on this **after** I have had a chance to print it out on monday"

After something has happened, you are looking back on it. In the past.